# Primefaces PDFExporter displaying Non ASCII letters as junk in the PDF

Tags: java, pdf, primefaces

Using PrimeFaces 6.0 `PDFExporter` to export data-table data to PDF.

Using below code for export:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":contactListform:contactDataTable");
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
com.lowagie.text.Document document = new com.lowagie.text.Document();
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();

com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);          

document.add(exportPDFTable(context, dataTable, false, false, "UTF-8"));
document.close();
writePDFToResponse(context.getExternalContext(), baos, filename);
```

**Issue:**  Non ASCII letters (For example Chinese letters ) are displaying as question mark symbol (????) in PDF.

Comment: if you would have tried with a plain itext you would have seen the same problem. Looking for the option to add an additional font (like seen in the answer) but it is true for plain itext as well.  If you are not running PF8, look for adding fonts statically to itext.

Answer (score 1):

See this ticket for the fix: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3585

PF 8.0 or higher allows you to set the Font of the PDF and you have to pick a font that supports the Chinese characters.

```java
PDFOptions pdfOpt = new PDFOptions();
pdfOpt.setFontName("Courier");
```

Obviously "Courier" does not but I am sure you have a font that supports Chinese characters you can set it to?

Comment: Any solution in PF6.0 without upgrading to PF8.0

Comment: Not that I am aware of but as @Kukeltje suggested look to "look for adding fonts statically to itext" if you can to make it work in PF 6.0